# Outlook change mail content before it is rendered in read mode

Tags: outlook, outlook-web-addins

Is there a way, to manipulate what the user is seeing in the Outlook read window?
I have some corrupt EML files, that have to be shown in Outlook after downloading them. So what I need is some extension point to run some js code before the user sees the content.

I already have an addin deployed and I found this topic: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/autolaunch
Which looks kind of promising, except there is no event that is triggered when the email viewer is loaded. Does anyone know a way to intercept the viewer screen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OfficeJS doesn't provide anything for that nowadays.